# Show a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I have to show that $f(t)$ is a solution to

$f'''+(\alpha +\beta )f''+(1+\alpha \beta +g_2)f'+g_1f=z'''+(\alpha +\beta )z''+(1+\alpha \beta )z'$

I have deduced that $u(t)=x'''+x''(\alpha +\beta )+x'(1+\alpha \beta)$, but I don't know if that helps anything. (The language is danish)

Comment: Use that $f = z-x \implies x = z - f$. Substitute this into your equation for $u(t) = x''' + \ldots $ and use the expression for $u = g_1 f + g_2 f'$ given in the text to finish it off.

Comment: I can't see how. I got this $g_1f+g_2f'=(z-f)'''+(z-f)''(\alpha +\beta )+(z-f)'(1+\alpha \beta)$ but what's next?

Comment: Use that $(z-f)''' = z''' - f'''$ (the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives) and similar for the other terms to split the right hand side into two pieces. In the end move all the $f$-terms ($f$, $f'$, etc.) to the left hand side of the equation.

Comment: But then I am back to the beginning: $f'''+f''(\alpha +\beta )+f'(1+\alpha \beta)+g_1f+g_2f'=z'''+z''(\alpha +\beta )+z'(1+\alpha \beta)$

Comment: I read the question as: this is what you want to show!

Comment: No, the question is, how can I show that $f(t)=z(t)-x(t)$ is a solution to 
$f'''+(\alpha +\beta )f''+(1+\alpha \beta +g_2)f'+g_1f=z'''+(\alpha +\beta )z''+(1+\alpha \beta )z'$. :-)

Comment: The question is missing details vital to be able to solve it. What is $x$ and what is the equation determining this? There is no info about this on the page (and I read danish).

Comment: True. I was also confused. Thanks for the help, anyway!